# Terme français pour « cliffhanger » ?

Tags: terminologie, anglicismes

Existe-t-il en français  un terme technique utilisé par les spécialistes de l'audiovisuel pour exprimer *[cliffhanger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliffhanger)* autrement que par une paraphrase du genre *moment de suspense à la fin de l'épisode* ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

D'après le [Journal Officiel du 16 octobre 2011](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do;jsessionid=B1200A849CDE52F5FC1A36AB647496A7.tpdjo12v_3?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000024668811&categorieLien=id), l'équivalent officiel pour *cliffhanger* est "**suspens**" :

> **suspens, n.m.** 
>   *Domaine* : Audiovisuel-Littérature. 
>   *Définition* : Effet dramatique visant à tenir le lecteur ou le spectateur en
>   haleine, notamment à la fin d'un chapitre, d'un épisode ou d'une
>   séquence. 
>   *Équivalent étranger* : cliffhanger.

Comment: Ce qui n'est pas vraiment satisfaisant. Ça m'étonnerait que ça prenne dans le langage courant, tout d'abord à cause de la confusion induite entre *suspense* */sys.pɛns/* et *suspens* */sys.pɑ̃/*.  Encore une fois la commission de terminologie et de néologie est plus animée par la « purification » de la langue que par l'esprit pratique ! Enfin, merci de toute façon pour la réponse !

Comment: @Laure Ta remarque est juste, mais on peut noter cependant une exception dans l'idiome *laissé en suspens* qui est relativement courant et ne cause pas spécialement de confusion. En revanche, l'usage du substantif *un suspens* serait effectivement très artificiel.

Answer (score 6):

Les séries d'épisodes sont [plus vieilles que la télévision](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OlderThanTelevision). Le principe était déjà décrit dans les [*1001 Nuits*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mille_et_Une_Nuits), mais je ne connais pas de terme courant pour désigner le procédé employé par Shéhérazade. Il a été popularisé au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle par les [romans-feuilletons](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman-feuilleton). [Gustave Vapereau](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustave_Vapereau) en parle en ces termes dans *L'année littéraire et dramatique* en 1861 :

> Qu'il soit déraisonnable de servir au public miettes par miettes, pendant des mois et des années, un inépuisable festin, [...] d'exciter au plus haut point l'attente et la curiosité du lecteur pour y répondre par l'éternel refrain : « la suite au prochain numéro », [...] c'est l'affaire du public de s'arranger de ces procédés de lecture à la Tantale ; et il s'en arrange.
>
> Tout est l'art de tenir la curiosité en éveil par la variété et l'imprévu. Dès l'origine du roman feuilleton, on avait inventé des procédés de **suspension savante** qui n'ont pas été dépassés ; on aimait surtout à dominer l'imagination par des menaces de terreur. [...] Et l'on remettait au prochain numéro une réponse, que l'auteur souvent n'avait pas encore trouvée. Ces procédés font rire aujourd'hui [...] ; et cependant je ne doute pas que si un auteur avait l'audace de les employer encore demain, ces ressorts vieillis, ces ficelles usées produiraient sur une partie de la masse qui sait lire un aussi grand effet que sur le public de certains théâtres les vieux épouvantails du mélodrame.

La [Commission générale de terminologie et de néologie](http://franceterme.culture.fr/FranceTerme/recherche.html) française préconise de traduire *cliffhanger* par **suspens**. Le dictionnaire canadien [Termium Plus](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&srchtxt=cliffhanger&index=ent&i=&sg_kp=10012462&fchrcrdnm=1#zz1) reprend cette traduction. Le terme [suspens](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suspens) désigne cependant plutôt le sentiment du lecteur ou spectateur (qui est dans l'attente, qui suspent son souffle...) que le procédé employé par l'artiste. Toutefois ce nom a eu tendance dans la deuxième moitié du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle à être supplanté par le nom masculin *[suspense](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suspense)* (prononcé [syspɑ̃s], ou à l'anglaise [syspεns]) dans le sens d'un sentiment d'attente angoissée ou impatiente. On peut parler de **point en suspens** pour le *plot point* laissé non résolu par le *cliffhanger*, mais je ne sais pas que ce terme soit particulièrement courant dans le milieu littéraire ou audiovisuel.

Sur [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=cliffhanger), outre l'emploi de *cliffhanger* en français et les termes *suspens* et *suspense*, on trouve souvent le mot **rebondissement**. Ce n'est toutefois pas un équivalent direct : si une série à *cliffhangers* doit bien avoir des rebondissements pour maintenir la surprise du public, on peut tout à fait avoir des rebondissements (des révélations et revirements de l'action) dans une œuvre d'un seul tenant.

Comment: Encore un adepte de tvtropes... luttant contre ce fameux [problème](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/JustForFun/TVTropesWillRuinYourVocabulary)! ;-)